# Can you write "x=10" without using the "=" sign?

Tags: c++

Any ideas how to approach it? Let's say using C++.

I want to clarify that the objective is not to write an equality operation without using the '=" sign, but to actually print the "x=10" string without using the "=" sign.

Comment: This is more a question for codegolf.

Comment: @PMF Too trivial for codegolf.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code golf

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int x{10};
    char thing{61};

    std::cout << "x" << thing << x << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: In C++03, just do `std::cout << "x" << (char)61 << 7 << std::endl;`.